# WinJS: does MVVM, MVP or MVC fit better with it?

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, windows-8, mvp, winjs

I am building a simple Windows 8 LOB application using Javascript (WinJS) and HTML. In the application I would not like to have any third party dependencies. When deciding on the application structure I'm debating which pattern would fit best with the technology and the WinJS framework.

My initial thoughts on the main advantages / disadvantages of using these patterns are as follow.

**MVVM**

[image: MVVM]

- Pro: Clean separation of business logic in the ViewModel, making (unit)testing of the BL  easy
- Con: WinJS only has one-time and one-way databinding implemented out of the box, two-way databinding and commanding (binding to events) is not. These have to be implemented in a custom way (which can get tricky if one wants to stick with mostly declarative syntax on the view).

**MVP**

[image: MVP]

- Pro: the presenter still contains all of the business logic together with the view logic and can be (unit)tested by itself. No data binding is needed in this approach.
- Con: both the View and the Presenter code will be more verbose than in the case of MVVM as they now have to notify each other on status changes. The View needs to forward events onto the Presenter and the Presenter has to update the View when its state changes.

**MVC**

[image: MVC]

- Pro: the View is very lightweight and no data binding is needed for this approach either.
- Con: the Controller has to register and handle input events (e.g. keyboard and mouse events) as well as contain the business logic. Compated to the ViewModel in MVVM and the Presenter in MVP this class would be the most bloated and somewhat more difficult to (unit) test.

Based on these I would choose MVP to build this app. Could you agree with this or contradict?

Comment: Polling or questions that are likely to create debate are considered off topic.

Comment: There is no "best" approach. It is entirely dependent on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post something because I liked the way you explained the different design patterns and the good graphics (btw, do you have a source on those? You should include it)

Your con for MVVM is that two-way updates would have to be implemented in a custom manner. But, with the MVP paradigm it seems that you would have to do this in a custom manner anyway. If you go with MVP, are you not using any databindings at all? I would say, go with MVVM and figure out a way to solve the WinJS issue. I'm not familiar with WinJS but it seems that you could wrap this in custom object / properties and fire changed events to handle data binding in some manner.